# Custom pivot_ui aggregator in python?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, streamlit, pivottable.js

Is there a way to create a custom aggregator for pivot_ui in python?
I'd like to do weighted averages and hide the details of the computation/field-mappings from users, and only provide meaningful labels in the custom aggregator dropdown. All examples of custom aggregators are in javascript. Is there a way to do it in python/jupyter?

eg. in javascript: ( from view-source:http://horner.github.io/pivottable/examples/montreal_2014.html )

```
    $(function () {
        var tpl =              $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates;
        $.get("montreal_2014.csv", function(montreal_2014) {
            $("#output").pivotUI($.csv.toArrays(montreal_2014), {
                aggregators: {
                    "Mean Temp (Celcius)":  
                        function() { return tpl.average()(["Mean Temp (C)"])},
```

in python:

```py
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
pivot_ui( df, rows=["day"], aggregators= ?? )
```

How do I define and pass a javascript function obj in jupyter notebook? could I somehow define it with %%javascript in a different cell and reference in python? or is there some magic in the streamlit.components.v1 that can accomplish this?

thanks

Comment: You might want to provide some code and an honest attempt. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `pivottablejs` library for `Python`, it looks like they return an `IFrame`. You can try `components.html` form `Streamlit`

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
import pandas as pd


t = pivot_ui(df)

with open(t.src) as t:
    components.html(t.read(), width=900, height=1000, scrolling=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ultibi](https://pypi.org/project/ultibi/) instead. It was build especially for *custom aggregators*, which you can define in python or rust. The [repo](https://github.com/ultima-ib/ultibi-frtb-book) has good examples, here is a quick one:

```py
import ultibi as ul
import polars as pl
import os
os.environ["RUST_LOG"] = "info" # enable logs
os.environ["ADDRESS"] = "0.0.0.0:8000" # host on this address

# Read Data
# for more details: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html
df = pl.read_csv("titanic.csv")

# Let's add some Custom Aggregators to our UI

# Standard Calculator - does not block GIL
def survival_mean_age(kwargs: dict[str, str]) -> pl.Expr:
    """Mean Age of Survivals
    pl.col("survived") is 0 or 1
    pl.col("age") * pl.col("survived") - age of survived person, otherwise 0
    pl.col("survived").sum() - number of survived
    """
    return pl.col("age") * pl.col("survived") / pl.col("survived").sum()

measures = [ ul.BaseMeasure(
                "SurvivalMeanAge",
                ul.StandardCalculator(survival_mean_age),
                aggregation_restriction="sum",
            ) ]
#create ul.DataSet
ds = ul.DataSet.from_frame(df, bespoke_measures=measures)
# host ui
ds.ui()
```

You can find out the full power of custom aggregators (beyond polars expressions) in the [relevant section of the userguide](https://ultimabi.uk/ultibi-frtb-book/intro.html).